# Is there a way to mark code as non-threadsafe in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, race-condition

Im trying to hunt down a race condition, and I come across a lot of suspecious functions. Most of them are not allowed to be called from two threads at the same time, but its hard to make sure they don't.

Is there some keyword to instruct the runtime to throw an exception as soon as a function is executing in parallel? I know I sometimes get an exception when another thread modifies a collection which im enumerating, but are safeguards like that enough to rely on?

The runtime can halt execution using the `lock` instruction, so all I need is a `lock` which throws an error.

Comment: Why not just use proper thread synchronization? Make sure only one threads enters the parts that are not multithreading safe.

Comment: Collections like List<T> are not thread-safe and the exception is not thrown for thread-safety reasons. The exception is thrown when a collection does not support being modified while being enumerated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx) for this:

```cs
bool entered = !Monitor.TryEnter(someLockObject);
try
{
    if (!entered)
        throw Exception("Multi-thread call!");

    // Actual code
}
finally
{
    if (entered)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(someLockObject);
    }
}
```

And it would be good to wrap that code in its own class:

```cs
public sealed class MultiThreadProtector : IDisposable
{
    private object syncRoot;

    public MultiThreadProtector(object syncRoot)
    {
        this.syncRoot = syncRoot;

        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failure!");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this.syncRoot);
    }
}
```

This way you can execute it as follows:

```cs
using (new MultiThreadProtector(someLockObject))
{
    // protected code.
}
```